# Making link underline higher and near the text

Tags: html, css

I was browsing the web when I saw this cool [link underline on wired.com](http://www.wired.com/2015/03/old-school-automaker-morgan-back-another-beauty/).
I was wondering how this is done. I tried adding a border to the button but that doesn't do it. Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are using `box-shadow` and `border-bottom` to underline the link,
like this:

```
<html>

<head>
<style>
a{
    border-bottom: 3px solid #b4e7f8;
    box-shadow: inset 0 -5px 0 #b4e7f8;
    color: inherit;
    text-decoration:none
}
a:hover{
    background-color: #b4e7f8;
}
</style>
</head>

    <a href="#"> The link </a>

<body>

</body>
</html>
```

If you are in chrome you could right click the link in the website then click inspect element to see the css properties of the element.

Comment: I'm using Safari, but I didn't see it in inspect element there

Comment: I think you could use Web Inspector in safari. see this [Inspect element in Safari](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5508711?tstart=0), then you could navigate to the element.

Answer (score 1):

You can right click on the linked in their website and select "inspect element" from the menu to see their styling. The override the standard "a" tag styling and add their own:

```
.link-underline a {
border-bottom: 3px solid #b4e7f8;
box-shadow: inset 0 -5px 0 #b4e7f8;
color: inherit;
-webkit-transition: background .15s cubic-bezier(.33,.66,.66,1);
transition: background .15s cubic-bezier(.33,.66,.66,1);
}

a {
-webkit-transition: color .15s cubic-bezier(.33,.66,.66,1);
transition: color .15s cubic-bezier(.33,.66,.66,1);
color: inherit;
text-decoration: none;
}

html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre, a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code, del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp, small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var, dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li, fieldset, form, label, legend, table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
border: 0;
outline: 0;
font-weight: inherit;
font-style: inherit;
font-family: inherit;
font-size: 100%;
vertical-align: baseline;
}
```

Comment: Yes I know that, but i didn't see it at that time

Answer (score 0):

You could do it something like:

```
a
    {
    border-bottom: 2px solid blue;
    box-shadow: inset 0 -2px 0 blue;
    }
```

To get a the `inset` larger, simply make the `-2px` smaller

To make the `border-bottom` larger, make the `2px` larger

If you are confused, follow these documentations:

box-shadow: [www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_box-shadow.asp](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_box-shadow.asp)

border: [www.w3schools.com/css/css_border.asp](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_border.asp)

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/kjtz5oeh/

```
   <ul>
        <li>
        <span><a href="#">hello</a></span>
        </li>  
    </ul>

    li {
        text-decoration:none;
        position:relative;
    }

    ul {
        list-style-type: none;
    }

    a {

        text-decoration:none;
        color:red;

    }

    span {
       position:absolute;
       border-bottom: 3px solid rgba(0,0,0,.4);
       height: 12px;

    }
```